# Using query to search through table based on vertical and horizontal values

Tags: google-sheets, sum, transpose, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a table for employees and dates, I want to find out how many cases they solved on an exact date. I tried using a query but it's not working for me as its a new challenge for me to make a query that works based on the horizontal and vertical values. here is an example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19x2jGYM7xt_WIZN_OGPwTe_7q26Jj57l9Z0PUmSv0I8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:H), 
 "where Col1 matches 'Day|"&I3&"'", 0)), 
 "select sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 ="&DATEVALUE(I2)&" 
  label sum(Col2)''")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you my lifesaver. it worked like charm. Stay healthy and safe <3 :)